# How to take screenshot of an uwp app samsung odyssey programatically?

Tags: uwp, windows-mixed-reality

I want to take the screenshot of my uwp app programatically , the app is built for samsung oddysey device .

Answer (score 0):

I am using the following code to make the screenshot of the whole screen in UWP:

```
RenderTargetBitmap render = new RenderTargetBitmap();
await render.RenderAsync(null);
var pixelBuffer = await render.GetPixelsAsync();
byte[] pixels = pixelBuffer.ToArray();
var wb = new WriteableBitmap(render.PixelWidth, render.PixelHeight);
using (Stream stream = wb.PixelBuffer.AsStream())
{
    await stream.WriteAsync(pixels, 0, pixels.Length);
}
```